# 0xC0049063 error in derived column component when converting text to date(SSIS)

Tags: ssis

I am trying to do the following:

- I have an excel sheet with a column called tDate. The values are in text(This excel is an output from a system, so we cannot configure the column types). The text values are or empty or dates(dd/mm/yyyy)
- The destination column in the db table is of nvarchar type
- Using Derived Column component in SSIS i am trying to convert the dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM.sss. I used the following expression for that:
  (ISNULL([tDate]) || TRIM([tDate]) == "") ? " " : (DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)RIGHT([tDate],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([tDate],4,2) + "-" + LEFT([tDate],2) + " " + "00:00:00.000"

It gives me the following error:

[Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[Tdate]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is your expression. I just removed DT_DBDATE before the Year part of your structure. You don't need it; since DataType is already NVARCHAR. Your destination table column is of the same type.

SourceData:

[image: SourceData]

Please use this in your derived column transformation.

```
(ISNULL(tDate) || TRIM(tDate) == "") ? " " : (DT_WSTR,10)RIGHT(tDate,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(tDate,4,2) + "-" + LEFT(tDate,2) + " " + "00:00:00.000"
```

If we run the package,

[image: Run Package]

And let's check destination table:

[image: FERT]

Comment: Thx for the reply, i get the following error: 
[Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "TDate" (135) to column "TDate" (6).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: I added an explanation at the bottom on how to solve a truncation problem. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: It still gives me the same error after changing truncation to ignore failure

Comment: @Henkiee20 Sorry for the late reply. please check my updated answer. I hope It solves your problem this time :)